# how to fix the gallery here?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, gallery

I am trying to use the Aria template which is a free template made with Bootstrap.
I am trying to use the gallery without the text .
Now when I remove the text from the lightbox the white background still appears.
**All I want is just the image with close button without text.**

[image: Lightbox image without Text]

Here is the demo code of the gallery

```
  <div class="element-item development">
          <a class="popup-with-move-anim" href="#project-1">
            <div class="element-item-overlay"><span></span></div>
            <img src="images/project-1.jpg" alt="alternative">
          </a>
        </div>
```

And here is the theme [Click here](https://demos.onepagelove.com/html/aria/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to remove `col-lg-4` whole tag and replace the `col-lg-8` with `col-lg-12` and also change class `img-fluid` to `w-100`

check the [link](https://prnt.sc/zy9qfb)

```
<div class="row">
            <button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close x-button">×</button>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img class="w-100" src="images/project-1.jpg" alt="alternative">
            </div> <!-- end of col -->
           
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working but still the white border about 100 pixels is shown on each side of Pic...

Comment: just add `p-0` class to the this tag 

`<div id="project-1" class="lightbox-basic zoom-anim-dialog p-0">`

[see this](https://prnt.sc/zyhk3y), please vote if you find some help. Thanks